# calling servlet from action class

Tags: java, servlets, struts

I am calling a servlet from an action class by using forward. It is then going to the servlet but it is not showing the output.

Actually I have create a PDF file which I need to show it on runtime. If I run that servlet only on server then it is showing the PDF file I want to.
But if I forward it from the action class it is not not showing anything.
I have given a simple condiiton on the action class like this:

```
 if(id.equals("SGSY"))
    {
    forward = mapping.findForward("SGSY");
    }
    else
    {
    forward = mapping.findForward("fail");
    }
```

After this it is going to servlet but not actually showing the output. I don't understand why. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *after this it is going to servlet but not actually showing the output.* It will look for mapping mapped in the struts-cofig.xml with id `SGSY` , if you want to call servlet then just redirect response to servlet serving PDF

Answer (score 1):

Try response.sendRedirect 1st instead of forward mapping,if it works it means there must be problem with your path

Comment: no there is no prblm in the path,becoz if it is it will not not reach to the servlet,it is reachin....i have check tht path is correct...i don'nt know wht's the prblm....i want it to run it like tht only...

Comment: @Neha: I find you extremely hard to understand. English is not my native language (and also not for many others on this international site), can you please spell out full words instead of using childish/SMS/street talk, so that everyone understands you?